# FullScreenIntent not working on xiaomi devices

Tags: android, xiaomi

I am developing a calling app. I need to show the ringing screen automatically after receiving push notification. It works ok except xiaomi-devices. Sometimes, the screen is not switched on. What is the secret for xiaomi-devices?
All permissions on the xiaomi-device are granted:

1. Background processes: no limit
2. Disabled battery optimizations
3. Autostart is on

What i use programmatically:

1.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder()
 .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
 .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
 .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true)
```

2. private fun showWhenLockedAndTurnScreenOn() {

   ```
         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
             setShowWhenLocked(true)
             setTurnScreenOn(true)
             val keyguardManager = getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager
             keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null)
         } else {
             window.addFlags(
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON or
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD or
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED or
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
             )
         }
     }
   ```
3. Manifest permissions:

for activity:

```
 android:showOnLockScreen="true"
```

for app:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
```

What am I missing out for Xiaomi?

Answer (score 2):

it seems that this code helped:

```
  fun asquireWake() {
    val mPowerManager = getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
    val mWakeLock: PowerManager.WakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(
        PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK or PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP,
        "App:IncomingCall"
    )
    mWakeLock.acquire(1*60*1000L /*1 minute*/)
}
```

I writed it before showing the notification.

Answer (score 1):

Xiaomi devices have a specific permission regarding full screen intents on the lock screen. You have to enable this permission manually:

1. Go to app settings and select *Other permissions*:

[image]

2. Select *Show on lock screen*:

[image]

3. Check *Always allow* on the pop-up:

[image]

This setting will ensure that your app displays full screen intent activities on the lock screen.

Comment: I will check it, thanks. Is it possible to enable this programmatically? I wonder how telegram, for example, did this. I don't think users have to enable all of this stuff in order to make calls work

Comment: As far as I am concerned there is no way to enable this programmatically. Popular applications are most likely whitelisted by the manufacturer and those apps have this permission enabled by default.

Comment: I checked, this setting is enabled, but still the problem is actual.

Comment: I found the solution with PowerManager. See my answer