# FullScreenIntent does not open an activity sometimes

Tags: android, push-notification

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75662575/fullscreenintent-not-working-on-xiaomi-devices) I described the problem about my call app. The display did not light up on push coming. That was solved with power manager. But now there is a new problem: sometimes a device's screen does light up, but the activity does not open. It happens at random. What could be the problem?
All permissions on the xiaomi-device are granted:

1. Background processes: no limit
2. Disabled battery optimizations
3. Autostart is on

What i use programmatically:

1.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder()
 .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
 .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
 .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true)
```

2. private fun showWhenLockedAndTurnScreenOn() {

   ```
         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
             setShowWhenLocked(true)
             setTurnScreenOn(true)
             val keyguardManager = getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager
             keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null)
         } else {
             window.addFlags(
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON or
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD or
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED or
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
             )
         }
     }
   ```
3. Manifest permissions:

for activity:

```
 android:showOnLockScreen="true"
```

for app:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
```

I writed it before showing the notification:

```
  fun asquireWake() {
    val mPowerManager = getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
    val mWakeLock: PowerManager.WakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(
        PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK or PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP,
        "App:IncomingCall"
    )
    mWakeLock.acquire(1*60*1000L /*1 minute*/)
}
```